ошибка при подключении к бд Oracle через cx_Oracle
около трех месяцев я подключалась в бд Oracle через библиотеку через cx_Oracle 8.3
login = ''
password = ''
dsn = ''
cx_Oracle.connect(login, password, dsn)

Все работало корректно, в самом .py скрипте никаких изменений я не делала, но день назад начала сыпаться ошибка
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed

Что я сделала:

проверила подключение к другой бд таким же способом - подключение есть
подключилась к проблемной бд через sql developer - подключение есть
установила oracledb самой последней версии, и подключение стало проходить
но так как я компилирую файл в exe, то через pyinstaller не подтягиваются все библиотеки при использовании oracledb и сам exe не запускается, хотя при установленной библиотеки cx_Oracle все компилируется корректно

По поводу бд - изменений никаких не было, на форумах много кто предлагает изменить файл tnsnames.ora прописать там значение SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
после этого начинает выскакивать другая ошибка
ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

В общем я бы хотела использовать библиотеку cx_Oracle, чтобы не переделывать все под oracledb и не мучаться с pyinstaller.
Но я все же не могу понять, почему подключение перестало проходить, хотя до этого 3 месяца работало корректно. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой ?
